# Filenames in Cloudflare Logpush

Tags: cloudflare

What are the file names of the logfiles create with Cloudflare LogPush? The file *format* is well documented, but I can't find any mention of the file *names*.

Some context: I want to migrate from another CDN provider to Cloudflare, with Logpush to Backblaze B2. I have a script running in a cronjob that generates some analytics data from the logs which I have to adapt to the different log file format and names.